# perl - Safely opening files

Tags: windows, perl, file, timeout

I am working on a Perl script where I need to check the content of multiple remotes files on different servers.
Inside my loop I got this:

```
my $file = "\\\\$myserver\\c\$\\$mydirectory\\$myfile";
if (open (FILE, "<", $file))
{
    # do some work
    close (FILE);
}
```

This is working fine most of the time but today I had a very specific problem. One of the servers had his Windows directory deleted and wasn't responsive.
I wasn't even able to kill the terminal running the script.
So I started to search online a way to add a timeout but after a long search I found this:

> Blocking I/O on MSWin32
>
> alarm(2) doesn't interrupt blocking I/O on MSWin32, so 'timeout' won't do that either.

Since almost all solution uses the function alarm I have no idea how to prevent my script from being stuck again.

ps: I tried to use system calls to print the file but I got the same issue even directly from a cmd and not inside the script.

Answer (score 0):

I belive the corect syntax for opening a file is:

```
 my $file = "\\\\$myserver\\c\$\\$mydirectory\\$myfile";
 open my $fh, '<', $file
     or die "Cannot open $file for reading: $!";
```

Comment: I'm not sure that actually helps the problem. The method the OP used to test if open worked is fine - it's just it's blocking, which wouldn't work either.

Comment: I agree with you it is a more elegant way to open file but it is not related to my problem